# Get records between 2 dates but sometimes they can be null

Tags: mysql, date

I have 2 dates in database: start_date and end_date(type DATE). Sometimes end_date can be null, which means that if start_date <= CURRENT DATE I need that record as well.
I added for now the condition for both dates set like `NOW() >= of.start_date AND NOW() < of.end_date`.
How can I get the records which have end_date = NULL (in the same query), which means that they are always active if the start_date <= NOW() (they won't start in future)?
There is also the possibility that neither start_date and end_date is set. In this case I also need those records as well. How can I achieve this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` or put the `NULL` logic in explicitly:

```
where now() >= of.start_date and (of.end_date >= now() or of.end_date is null)
```

Comment: Great! I don't know how I didn't think at that. I added also the other condition : (NOW() >= of.start_date AND (of.end_date >= NOW() OR of.end_date IS NULL)) OR (of.start_date IS NULL AND of.end_date IS NULL) and seems fine

Comment: Actually I noticed a problem regarding NULL. When I submit my form with no start and/or end date the value in field is 0000-00-00. Final condition is (NOW() >= of.start_date AND (of.end_date >= NOW() OR of.end_date = '0000-00-00')) OR (of.start_date = '0000-00-00' AND of.end_date = '0000-00-00')